# How to get current user's tenant id rather than application's tenant id in MS Teams tab app (React JS)

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

I am building a MS Teams Tab app using React JS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs. For each app, we need to create an App Registration in Azure console. Now, in my application I am trying to retrieve the logged in user's tenant ID rather than app tenant ID.

First thing I know is that I can get the tenant ID from SSO token. So I tried to retrieve the SSO token as follow using `@microsoft/teams-js` package.

```
initialize();

    const authOptions: authentication.AuthTokenRequest = {
      successCallback:(token) => {
           // when I decode the token, the tid field is still  giving me app registration tenant's id (user can be guest and can belong to different tenant)
       },
      failureCallback:(error) => {

     },
    };

    authentication.getAuthToken(authOptions);
```

(Note the comment in the code above).

I can get the user's tenant ID if I force the user to login using MSAL with this libraries, `@azure/msal-react` and `@azure/msal-browser`. The access token gives me the tid of the user. But the thing is that I do not want to force the user to login. How can I get the user's tennant ID without forcing the user to login?

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=teamsjs-v2#get-context-by-using-the-microsoft-teams-javascript-library

Comment: The token returned from `getAuthToken` should have the tid of the user's -actual- tenant - I've tested now to confirm.. The problem might not be `getAuthToken`, but rather somehow that the user is signing in as a guest - they're logging in as a -guest-, but into your main tenant. In contrast, when you're using msal, they're logging in with their -actual- login in their home tenant.

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve it, but maybe that helps steer your in some way

Comment: Hey both. Thanks so much. Yes the `getAuthToken` gives us the user's actual tenant. Somewhere in my code, I hardcoded the tenant ID. Thanks.